# Cplex/Opl adding constraint of making the sum of x number of columns equal to 0

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I have a 2d array with binary decision variables, my goal is to add constraint of, sum of specific number of columns equals to 0.

Comment: I think we're gonna need a few more details if anyone is going to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
int N=5;
range r=1..N;
{int} zeroColumns={1,3};

dvar boolean x[r][r];

maximize sum(i,j in r) x[i][j];
subject to
{
  forall(i in zeroColumns) 0==sum(j in r) x[j][i];
}
```

gives

```
0   1   0   1   1
0   1   0   1   1
0   1   0   1   1
0   1   0   1   1
0   1   0   1   1
```